# Transform XML to different layout

Tags: xml, transform

Hi and Thank you in Advance

Given this Input XML

```
<root>
<part id='74'>
    <title>Belt</title>
    <description>1158J5</description>
    <partno>C00112576</partno>
    <price>10.99</price>
</part>
<category id='6' name='Washer-Dryer'></category>
<category id='2' name='Washing machine'></category>
<make id='6' name='Ariston'></make>
<make id='2' name='Hotpoint'></make>
<make id='33' name='Indesit'></make>
<model catid='2' catname='Washing machine' makeid='6' makename='Ariston' modelid='524'>A1235</model>
<model catid='2' catname='Washing machine' makeid='2' makename='Hotpoint' modelid='413'>SCR37P</model>
<model catid='2' catname='Washing machine' makeid='2' makename='Hotpoint' modelid='35751'>WD440</model>
<model catid='6' catname='Washer-Dryer' makeid='33' makename='Indesit' modelid='2989'>WF000G</model>
```

I would like to transform it to

```
<root>
<part id='74'>
    <title>Belt</title>
    <description>1158J5</description>
    <partno>C00112576</partno>
    <price>10.99</price>
</part>
<category id='6' name='Washer-Dryer'>
    <make id='33' name='Indesit'>
        <model catid='6' catname='Washer-Dryer' makeid='33' makename='Indesit' modelid='2989'>WF000G</model>
    </make>
</category>
<category id='2' name='Washing machine'>
    <make id='6' name='Ariston'>
        <model catid='2' catname='Washing machine' makeid='6' makename='Ariston' modelid='524'>A1235</model>
    </make>
    <make id='2' name='Hotpoint'>
        <model catid='2' catname='Washing machine' makeid='2' makename='Hotpoint' modelid='413'>SCR37P</model>
        <model catid='2' catname='Washing machine' makeid='2' makename='Hotpoint' modelid='35751'>WD440</model>
    </make>
</category>
```

I receive this XML from a asp classic feed, i have access to the asp and could do it there, once recieved i am in in php, i then send to a xsl transform to output to the browser

So my question is which would be the best way to go ie asp, php or xsl and would it possible to at least start me off on the best way to do this

many Thanks again
Tim dodgson

Comment: why don't you just do that during the XSL transformation that you mentioned? else php will the most convenient for you

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, i was hoping xsl would be the way to go, but alass i am no wizz at xsl and would really apreciate a start if somebody has the time, a bit more clarifercation there can be difernt anount of catergory, models and makes each time and the cat make and model id's can be different vales

Comment: Your (so-called) XML isn't well-formed: the model elements (in both input and output) have two attributes with the same name (makeid). Before anyone can help you, you need to sort this out. Also, I think you need to think carefully about whether you really want an XSLT transformation if you have no skills to understand it or maintain it. I would advise making some kind of attempt to read up on the language and tackle the problem yourself before you ask for help.

Comment: Thank you again for the reply, i have fixed the attributes as requested(my bad sorry). I have a understanding of xsl and i can match templates do for next loops and conditional jumps,, but to do this seems a higher level of programming ith xsl so it would be a good learning curve, If somebody has the time to start me with some code it would be greatly appreciated Again Many Thanks Tim

Answer (score 0):

well  day of googling and pulling my hair out and i have come up with this

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="//make">
        <xsl:variable name="makeid" select="@id" />
        <xsl:variable name="makename" select="@name" />
        <make id="{$makeid}" name="{$makename}">
        <xsl:for-each select="//model[@makeid = $makeid]">
            <model catid="{@catid}" catname="{@catname}" makeid="{@makeid}" makename="{@makename}" modelid="{@modelid}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </model>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </make>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
```

I know its not quite what i wanted at first but it is ok for my needs. was just hoping if some one could say if i was at least heading the right way

many Thanks tim